# How to customize windows 7 installation disk on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, wine

I want to customize the Windows 7 x64 Ultimate installation disk preferably using RT Se7en lite but other softwares will also be fine but how do I run them on ubuntu? I don't want to use a virtual machine. I tried to use Wine but RT Se7en lite needs WAIK to run which I don't think is available for ubuntu...

Comment: Why are you against using a virtual machine?  Microsoft provides free virtual machines for exactly this purpose ( actually to test IE ) but would serve you well in a case like this.

Comment: @Ramhound i don't have enough bandwidth to download a virtual machine... btw, can you still give me the link of the one smallest and best for this purpose.

Comment: It's in Microsoft's website dedecated to IE testing